# How to update a field in Object with nested array by using arrow function

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

My Object nested array is following way,

```
const formInitValue = {
    name: '',
    description: '',
    points: [
      {
        x1: undefined,
        x2: undefined,
        x3: undefined,
        x4: undefined,
        x5: undefined,
      },
       {
        x1: undefined,
        x2: undefined,
        x3: undefined,
        x4: undefined,
        x5: undefined,
      },
       {
        x1: undefined,
        x2: undefined,
        x3: undefined,
        x4: undefined,
        x5: undefined,
      },      
    ],
  };
```

I want to update x5 field with points array index, How can I achieve this by using ES6 arrow function.
I wrote a function but It doesn't work for me. It would be great if someone can correct my function,

```
 const replaceWithIndex = (values: any) => {
    return (
     values.points.map((p: any, index: number) => ({
      x5: index,
    }))
    )
  };
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share your expected output? The `x5` key already holds the index of the object in the points array.

Comment: I updated initial object array above, Please note that I didn't consider other values which populates by the application and I want to update x5 field value as follows,

Comment: I want to update x5 field value as follows,   expexctedObjectArray = {
    name: ignore,
    description: ignore,
    points: [
      {
       ---
        x5: 0,
      },
    {
       ---
        x5: 1,
      },
    {
       ---
        x5: 2,
      },   
    ],
  };

Comment: Is `---` the other "x" properties? I've provided an [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68138875/5648954), you can see the fiddle to see if it produces the correct output.

Comment: Yes --- other properties, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return a new object, that has all the properties of your initial `formInitValue` object by using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `...`. As this copies over all properties from your original object, it will copy the `points` array. You can overwrite this array with a newly mapped points array. For each object in the points array, you can again use the spread syntax to create a new object with all the `x1`, `x2`, etc... properties from the currently iterated object, and then overwrite the `x5` property to hold the current index:

```js
const formInitValue = { name: '', description: '', points: [ { x1: undefined, x2: undefined, x3: undefined, x4: undefined, x5: undefined, }, { x1: undefined, x2: undefined, x3: undefined, x4: undefined, x5: undefined, }, { x1: undefined, x2: undefined, x3: undefined, x4: undefined, x5: undefined, }, ], };

const replaceWithIndex = formObj => ({
  ...formObj,
  points: formObj.points.map((point, x5) => ({
    ...point,
    x5
  }))
});

console.log(replaceWithIndex(formInitValue));
```

You can also consider making interfaces instead of typing your objects with `any`. See typescript implementation below:

```
interface IPoint {
  x1?: number;
  x2?: number;
  x3?: number;
  x4?: number;
  x5?: number;
};

interface IForm {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  points: IPoint[];
};

const formInitValue: IForm = { name: '', description: '', points: [ { x1: undefined, x2: undefined, x3: undefined, x4: undefined, x5: undefined, }, { x1: undefined, x2: undefined, x3: undefined, x4: undefined, x5: undefined, }, { x1: undefined, x2: undefined, x3: undefined, x4: undefined, x5: undefined, }, ], };

const replaceWithIndex = (formObj: IForm): IForm => ({
  ...formObj,
  points: formObj.points.map((point: IPoint, x5: number) => ({
    ...point,
    x5
  }))
});
```